# Injective sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

I am trying to verify that:

> A sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules $\mathcal{F}$ is an injective object in the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules iff its local rings $\mathcal{F}_x$ are injective $\mathcal{O}_x$ modules for each $x\in X$.

I have a proof(??) to say that this is actually true but it is too long to write here. I would write here if it is false, then some one can point out the wrong justification that I have given. If it is true and well known it is of not much use to write down here.

If not for any scheme $X$ is it true for Noetherian schemes atleast?
Any suggestion  is welcome.

Comment: By Proposition II.7.17 in Hartshorne's _Residues and duality,_ this holds if $X$ is locally noetherian and $\mathcal{F}$ is quasicoherent.

Comment: @FredRohrer Thanks for your comment. I have not yet seen that book as I have started to understand sheaf cohomology (which is where I had to use this result) only recently. I think this is the best reason to look at that book at least if not to really understand the proof. Thank you.

Comment: @FredRohrer I was giving some wrong justification which I have realised. Lemma 7.12 says that even for one direction it needs the assumption that $X$ is locally noetherian. It says the following: Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian prsescheme, and let $\mathcal{I}$ be an injective $\mathcal{O}_X$ module. Then the stalk $\mathcal{I}_x$ of $\mathcal{I}$ at each point $x\in X$ is an injective module over the local ring $\mathcal{O}_x$ of $x$. Your comment is very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Praphulla, the result you cite does not say that it _needs_ local noetherianness. However, I suspect that this hypothesis can indeed not be omitted (since, for modules over rings, localisation does not necessarily preserve injectivity in a non-noetherian situation, cf. work of Dade).

Comment: @FredRohrer : :) By "... needs .." I mean they have used the condition of local noetherian. Yes, I do remember seeing something which says there are Injective modules over a non noetherian ring such that their localizations are not injective modules over repsective localization of rings. Yes, I have heard about the paper by Everett C Dade which is online here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869381902131

Comment: If we restrict ourselves to quasicoherent modules (but still work in the category of modules), asking for the class of schemes for which the statement holds is equivalent to this (still unanswered) [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/140631).